# UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat Completion?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I am doing a very simple repeating animation to fade a label in and out, seen below. I assumed the completion block would be called every time the animation finishes, but when using `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` it is never called. So how am I supposed to stop this animation?

I know I can use `[self.lbl.layer removeAllAnimations];`, however that ends its very abruptly. I want to know when it has finished a cycle of the animation so I can stop it at that time.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            self.lbl.alpha = 0;

        } completion:^(BOOL finished){
            if (finished) NSLog(@"done");

        }];
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of your earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648913/stop-repeating-uiview-animation-block ?

Comment: I see your thinking but its not quite the same situation. This time I am using `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` which changes the functionality of the animation block. `removeAllAnimations` is also a very harsh way of ending an animation when it could be at any state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this kind of solution using a selector can help you:

```
- (void) animateTextWithMax:(NSNumber *)max current:(NSNumber *)current
{
    NSLog(@"max = %d, current = %d",max.intValue, current.intValue);
    textlabel.alpha = 1.0f;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                     animations:^{
                         textlabel.alpha = 0.0f;
                     }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"finished");
                         if (current.intValue < max.intValue) {
                             [self performSelector:@selector(animateTextWithMax:current:) withObject:max withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(current.intValue+1)]];
                         }

                     }];
}
```

then you can call the animation by this way:

```
[self animateTextWithMax:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] current:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
```

Maybe this is not the best solution because you are not using the `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` option, but I think it can work.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the animation with the *UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat* option to be finite, you have to set the repeat count via *+ (void)setAnimationRepeatCount:(float)repeatCount* of UIView.

In case of block-based animation (that is your case), you should set repeat count from within animation block. So, here is your code modified:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:4]; // 4 as example here
        self.lbl.alpha = 0;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        if (finished) NSLog(@"done");

    }];
```

This is mentioned in documentation of [`setAnimationRepeatCount:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationRepeatCount:) method of UIView.

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, the completion block is not called, because the animation never ends. Off the top of my head, you've got two options:

- Add another animation to the label, setting it to your desired final value, with the `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` option. I'm not sure what effect this has on the existing, repeating animation, though. If that doesn't work...
- Get the current position of your animation by examining the `label.layer.presentationLayer`. Stop all animations, set your value to the current state, then add a new animation to transition from the current state to the desired final state.